# How to get combinations of n items from a list of items in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, combinations

I need to generate of all combinations of size n from a list of items. I am trying to solve this functionally using recursion. Here is my solution:

```scala
  def combinations(i: Int, value: List[Symbol]): List[List[Symbol]] = {
    if (i == 0) List(Nil)
    else if (i == value.size) List(value)
    else value match {
      case Nil => List(Nil)
      case head::tail => {
        combinations(i, tail) ::: combinations(i - 1, tail) map { tailCombos => head :: tailCombos }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my test input:
`combinations(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd ))`

I am getting 
`List(List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd), List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd), List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd), List('a, 'b, 'c))`

instead of 
`List(List('b, 'c, 'd), List('a, 'b, 'd), List('a, 'c, 'd), List('a, 'b, 'c))`

There are other solutions I can refer to, so please don't give me some working solution. However I want to know why my code doesn't work and what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing more than some syntactic confusion. The white space based syntax (there is a name for it but i forgot) was introduced in the early days and has caused nothing but confusion. I highly recommend sticking to the dot syntax.

What is happening is because of the left to right evaluation, map is being applied to the entire result of `combinations(i, tail) ::: combinations(i - 1, tail)`

instead if you did

```
 combinations(i, tail) ::: combinations(i - 1, tail).map{ tailCombos => head :: tailCombos }
```

You will get the result you want.

Working scastie --> https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dV3BJ9fIQBSckt1LLTfbrw

P.S. If you are using cats, you can rely on built in combine on semigroups to generate this as well

Comment: My bad, I had doubts about the algorithm rather than the syntax so didn't think that infix notation could be the problem. Yes, I will stick to dot notation wherever possible.